# finding out the maximum number of days of booking in a year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a online hotel management system project,which database is in mssql and having a table name BookingDetails which conatins the columns names as BookingId,BookingFrom,and RoomNo.
I need to find out the RoomNo that are booked for maximum number of days in a year.
I have found the rooms with bookingid is booked for how many days;
like

```
select
    RoomNo
    BookingId,
    BookingUpto-BookingFrom

from 
    BookingDetails;
```

that provides the result the number of days of booking for different rooms,now my question is how to use the exerted data i,e number of days with min,max or count function. Plz help.
Thank you .

table name BookingDetails

```
BookingID  BookingFrom               BookingUpto             RoomNo
Id
111        12/22/2013 12:00:00 AM    12/25/2013 12:00:00 AM  101
222        12/23/2013 12:00:00 AM    12/25/2013 12:00:00 AM  210
333        12/24/2013 12:00:00 AM    12/26/2013 12:00:00 AM  305
444        1/4/2014 12:00:00 AM      1/6/2014 12:00:00 AM    101
555        12/28/2013 12:00:00 AM    1/10/2014 12:00:00 AM   305
666        12/29/2013 12:00:00 AM    1/2/2014 12:00:00 AM    210
777        1/20/2014 12:00:00 AM     1/28/2014 12:00:00 AM   305
888        1/29/2014 12:00:00 AM     1/31/2014 12:00:00 AM   101
NULL       NULL                      NULL                    NULL
```

Comment: What about you start giving us some more details about thoose tables? Like tables structure for start. With only one of then no one here will be able to help you.

Comment: Can you tell us what results you expect from the above sample data?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand :

select RoomNo, sum(datediff(day, BookingFrom, BookingUpto)) as daysbooked
from BookingDetails
group by RoomNo;

This gives us result as;
RoomNo daysbooked
101 7
210 6
305 23

But I want result as only;
RoomNo daysbooked
305 25

Answer (score 2):

The following gives the number of days that each room is booked in the year:

```
select RoomNo, sum(datediff(day, BookingFrom, BookingUpto)) as daysbooked
from BookingDetails
group by RoomNo;
```

You can find the rooms with the most days booked by sorting this list:

```
select RoomNo, sum(datediff(day, BookingFrom, BookingUpto)) as daysbooked
from BookingDetails
group by RoomNo
order by daysbooked desc;
```

Comment: select RoomNo, sum(datediff(day, BookingFrom, BookingUpto)) as daysbooked
from BookingDetails
group by RoomNo;

This gives us result as;
RoomNo daysbooked
101 7
210 6
305 23

But I want result as only;
RoomNo daysbooked
305 25

Comment: @user3238912 . . . Then add `top 1` to the select to get only one row.

Answer (score 0):

Try using subquery this will return the Max days for specific Room No.

```
select t.RoomNo, max(t.days)  from (
select RoomNo, BookingId, BookingUpto-BookingFrom days From BookingDetails) t
group by t.RoomNo
```

Comment: Please review with my last update, it should work, it is not return anything ?

Comment: "test.BookingDetails" is invalid object.

Comment: select t.RoomNo, max(t.days)  from (
select RoomNo, BookingId, BookingUpto-BookingFrom days From BookingDetails) t
group by t.RoomNo     >>>>  its working,but not displaying the maximum number of booked days for a room

Comment: using your date for room 101 I obtained 3 days with the query above. But yeah, BookingUpto-BookingFrom not working correctly with different years. I assume that and I was wrong. XD.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:-

```
SELECT SUM(DateDiff * TotalCount) NumberOfDays,
       RoomNo
FROM   (SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(day, BookingFrom, BookingUpTo)) DateDiff,
               RoomNo,
               count(1) TotalCount
        FROM   BookingDetails
        GROUP  BY BookingFrom,BookingUpTo,RoomNo) t
GROUP  BY RoomNo
ORDER  BY RoomNo
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get what you are looking for.  The group is on a per year and room.  From that I am computing a sum() of the number of days per booking.  So, if someone booked from Jan 1 to Jan 4, that should be 3 nights booked (checking out on the 4th).  Then another person books the room from Jan 4 to Jan 5 (one night). for a total of 4 nights booked.  Each individual booking computes IT's nights stay and adds them up.

```
SELECT
      YEAR( BookingUpTo ) as Yr,
      roomNo,
      SUM( datediff( day, BookingUpTo, BookingFrom )) as totalBookedDays
  from 
     BookingDetails
  group by
     YEAR( BookingUpTo ),
     roomNo
  order by
     totalBookedDays DESC
```